# Match Columns in Table A to Row Values in Table B to update another Column in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to match columns of TableA to values in one column of TableB, in order to update values in another column in TableB.

TableA:

| 001100 | 001200 | 003000 | 004000 | 005000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

TableB:

| Column_1 | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 001100 |  |
| 001200 |  |
| 003000 |  |
| 004000 |  |
| 005000 |  |

So, for example, I want the "Score" column in TableB to be updated with value "1" for 001100. Hence the result table should look like:

| Column_1 | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 001100 | 1 |
| 001200 | 0 |
| 003000 | 1 |
| 004000 | 1 |
| 005000 | 0 |

I know how to update this through hard-coding and one row at a time:

```
Update [TableB]
Set Score = [001100]
From  [Table A]
Where [Column_1] = '001100'
```

But I have over 50 such columns, so it would be great if someone could suggest how I can get this done without having to hard-code the column names. So a code that will dynamically fetch the names of the columns from TableA and then match it with tableB Column_1 values.

Comment: Is there only 1 row in `[TableA]`? Are the column names in `[TableA]` fixed (known and do not change)? Why does `001100` in `[TableB]` have a score of 0 instead of 1 (since it is 1 in TableA)?

Comment: Have you looked at JOINS?

Comment: Hi Ryan,
In [TableA] there will be more that one row. But at a time, I will be filtering/selecting only one row. Hence, I kept only one row in the example above. And yes, column names in [TableA] remain fixed. And about the last part, it was a typo. i fixed it now, thanks :)

Comment: Hi Brad, I am not being able to use joins as the commonality is between row and column, not column to column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

This will dynamically generate the correct SQL to update the `Score` in `Table B` from the values in `Table A` for *any number* of columns.

The only requrement is the names of the columns in `Table A` match the values of `Column_1` in `table B`

First I need a list of the columns, this can be obtained from `sys.columns`.
I then concatenated them into a string using `for xml path`.

Then I'm able to dynamically build an update statement that uses the column list and unpivots them to match the rows in `TableB`

Finally execute the dynamically built SQL.

Provided you have suitable indexes on the (actual) tables, this will be highly performant.

```
create table TableA ([001100] int, [001200] int, [003000] int, [004000] int [005000] int)

insert into TableA
select 1,0,1,1,0

create table TableB (Column_1 varchar(10), Score int)

insert into TableB (Column_1) select '001100'   
insert into TableB (Column_1) select '001200'   
insert into TableB (Column_1) select '003000'   
insert into TableB (Column_1) select '004000'   
insert into TableB (Column_1) select '005000'



declare @cols nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)

select @cols=Stuff((
        select ', '+QuoteName(c.name )
        from sys.tables t join sys.columns c on c.object_id=t.object_id
        where t.[name]='TableA'
        for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)'), 1, 2, ''
)

set @sql='
update b set
    b.score=p.val
from (
    select ' + @cols + '
    from TableA -- where clause if relevant
) s
unpivot (
 val for col in (' + @cols + ')
) p
join TableB b on b.Column_1=p.col'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Nice. You could also automate the `insert into TableB (Column_1) select '001100'` code, because if the row doesn't exist in `TableB`, then that row will not be updated. Also, if the processing code is run repeatedly, then `TableB` might need to be cleared out before the next run.

Comment: The insert into tableB is just the set-up code for testing, it's not part of the solution. Inserting these rows is down to the OP and I assume not a problem!

Answer (score 1):

If your column names in `TableA` are fixed and do not change, you can build a temporary table and update against the temporary table:

```
DECLARE @Scores TABLE (Column_1 varchar(20), Score int)

-- Build the data in the temporary table
INSERT @Scores (Column_1, Score)
SELECT '001100', [001100] FROM TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '001200', [001200] FROM TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '003000', [003000] FROM TableA
-- Repeat for all columns

UPDATE TableB
SET    Score = s.Score
FROM   TableB JOIN @Scores s ON TableB.[Column_1] = s.[Column_1]
```

You will need to manage the data in the temporary data if there is more than one row in `TableA`. In other words, if your temporary table contains multiple rows for the same row in `TableB`, then the update will not work like you expect. You would need to group and sum the scores:

```
-- Build the data in the temporary table
INSERT @Scores (Column_1, Score)
SELECT '001100', SUM([001100]) FROM TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '001200', SUM([001200]) FROM TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '003000', SUM([003000]) FROM TableA
-- Repeat for all columns
```

Here is an example:

```
-- Source data
DECLARE @TableA TABLE([001100] int, [001200] int, [003000] int, [004000] int, [005000] int);
DECLARE @TableB TABLE([Column_1] varchar(20), Score int);

INSERT @TableA ([001100], [001200], [003000], [004000], [005000])
VALUES  (1, 0, 1, 1, 0);

INSERT @TableB ([Column_1])
VALUES ('001100'), ('001200'), ('003000'), ('004000'), ('005000');

-- Answer
DECLARE @Scores TABLE (Column_1 varchar(20), Score int);

INSERT @Scores (Column_1, Score)
SELECT '001100', SUM([001100]) FROM @TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '001200', SUM([001200]) FROM @TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '003000', SUM([003000]) FROM @TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '004000', SUM([004000]) FROM @TableA
UNION ALL SELECT '005000', SUM([005000]) FROM @TableA
;

UPDATE TableB
SET    Score = s.Score
FROM   @TableB TableB JOIN @Scores s ON TableB.[Column_1] = s.[Column_1];

SELECT * FROM @TableB;
```

Here are the results:

| Column_1 | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 001100 | 1 |
| 001200 | 0 |
| 003000 | 1 |
| 004000 | 1 |
| 005000 | 0 |